Uniform waiting time
I am trying to figure out, given an event whose occurrence is uniformly distributed on $[5,15]$, what the expected waiting time for the next occurrence would be if you started following it at $t=100$.
I think the idea is that at $t=100$, an event could have happened at $t=95$, in which case it must occur again in the next $10$ minutes (no memoryless property). However, since the average time of occurrence on $[5,15]$ is $10$, my intuition tells me that repeating this process many times would show that the average waiting time is $10$ minutes after $t=100$, i.e. $t=110$. I don't think this is actually the case though, and from an intuitive or theoretical perspective I don't know why, and I'm having trouble simulating it.

Do you mean that after the event occurs, it occurs next time in $5$ to $15$ minutes?

If I understand the process, you draw from that sample, wait that allotted time, and then draw again.    Right?  If so, where is the difficulty in the simulation?  you just generate numbers from the given distribution and add the values sequentially, stopping the first time you get over $100$.

@lulu that was my approach to simulating it, and I was getting approximately 105 as the answer. The question (from Grinstead and Snell) is simply that there is a sequence of occurrences and that the time between them is uniform [5,15], and to figure out what the average waiting time for the next occurrence is from T=100. So part of my question I guess is whether I'm even interpreting it correctly.

105 makes sense heuristically. On average, the events happen once every 10 minutes, so if you enter at a random time you expect to wait half of that (5 minutes).

I don't know a simple solution to this, but we can go at it with some heavy machinery. Let $T_n \sim \mathsf{Uniform}(5, 15)$ be independent for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and define a stopping time
$$\tau_0 := \inf \left\{ \tau \in \mathbb{N} : \sum_{n=1}^\tau T_n \geq 100 \right\}$$
and observe $\tau_0 \leq 20$ almost surely. Next define a martingale
$$X_k := \sum_{n=1}^k T_n - k \mathbb{E}\left[ T_k \right]$$
and apply the Optional Stopping Theorem to deduce
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ X_{\tau_0} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ X_0 \right] = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\tau_0} T_n \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \tau_0 \right] \mathbb{E}\left[ T_{\tau_0} \right] = 10 \mathbb{E}\left[ \tau_0 \right]$$
Our waiting time from $t = 100$ onwards is given by
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\tau_0} T_n \right] - 100 = 10 \mathbb{E}\left[ \tau_0 \right] - 100$$
so it just remains to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[ \tau_0 \right]$.
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \tau_0 \right] = \sum_{\tau = 1}^\infty \Pr\left( \tau_0 \geq \tau \right) = \sum_{\tau = 1}^
{20} \Pr\left( \tau_0 \geq \tau \right) = \sum_{\tau = 1}^{20} \Pr\left( \sum_{n=1}^\tau T_n < 100 \right)$$
where we can use the Irwin-Hall distribution to get a closed form for $\Pr\left( \sum_{n=1}^\tau T_n < 100 \right)$.
